# Oatmeal Peanut Butter Raisin Chocolate Chip Nut Cookies

Tags: baking

I have a large oatmeal cookie recipe. For the oatmeal, choc chips, raisins  and nuts they say to stir them in by  hand but the recipe is so large that I can't stir them.  Due to getting older I no longer have the strength in my arm to do that.  Is it possible to mix them in the standing mixer without changing the texture of the cookies.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely the hand mixing is to avoid breaking the nuts apart and smearing chips and/or raisins.  Just use the mixer on a low speed, and only until mixed.  You should not have a problem.  I always use a mixer for cookies, regardless of add-ins.  This step will have minimal impact on cookie texture, whereas, the proper creaming of butter and sugar, as well as emulsifying/whipping in eggs will.